# How should I configure Turbolinks to handle a 401 return code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, http-status-code-401, turbolinks

If you attempt to sign with invalid credentials, you get a 401. Turbolinks isn't showing the HTML on that page with the validation error. Shouldn't it be? Do I need to configure ajax.failure to replace the HTML?